# Simba Spark ODBC .NET C# Driver Parameters in nested SQL Queries

Tags: c#, apache-spark, odbc

I'm having some trouble with Simba Spark ODBC Driver for C#, parameters work fine for a simple query but they do not work at all for the following nested query.

If I do a quick and dirty string replace of the parameters it works fine, so the query does work, it's the parameters.

```
SELECT *
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT DateColumn1, TN, w.start AS DateColumn2, Status,
          mean(Value) OVER (
            PARTITION BY TN, w.start
            ORDER BY DateColumn2 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
          ) AS Value
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              DateColumn2,
              WINDOW(DateColumn2, '10 minutes') w,
              TN,
              Status,
              DateColumn1,
              Value
            FROM
              some_table_name
            WHERE
              TN = ? AND
              DateColumn1 BETWEEN ?
              AND ? 
          )
)
```

And Here's the code that I use to call it. Assume that a connection and command has been successfully created

```
var command = await connectionManager.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = theQuery;
command.Parameters.Add("@TN", OdbcType.Text).Value = tagName;
command.Parameters.Add("@from", OdbcType.Date).Value = from;
command.Parameters.Add("@to", OdbcType.Date).Value = to;

var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

The same code works fine for a simple `select * from ... where ...`  query, but when I run it with the one above I get the following error which seems to indicate that the parameters couldn't be inserted, for some reason...

```
ERROR [HY000] [Simba][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message: 'MALFORMED_REQUEST: 
extraneous input '?' expecting {'(', '{', 'CALLED', 'CLONE', 'COLLECT', 'CONTAINS', 
'CONVERT', 'COPY', 'COPY_OPTIONS', 'CREDENTIALS', 'DEEP', 'DEFINER', 'DELTA', 
'DETERMINISTIC', 'ENCRYPTION', 'EXPECT', 'FAIL', 'FILES', 'FORMAT_OPTIONS'.
```

Do you have any ideas? It's complaining about the `?`, and I think I've given it everything it needs. But apparently not...

Comment: `tagname`, `from` and `to` are all not null, right?

Comment: @rene No they all have values :)

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: Hi @brajeshjaishwal no, unfortunately... we ended up doing a workaround with either a stored procedure or a function. Can't remember which one right now. Newer versions might have fixed this. I don't know

Comment: situation is still same, odbc only supports sql-1992 dialect, so nested query might not be a thing.
I would recommend exporting the join query as a view in Databricks and use simple query